# Creating/Saving DirectDraw Surface (DDS) Image via Imagick

Tags: php, imagemagick, imagick

This is the first time I use PHP Imagick and experiencing problems with it.

I'm creating a website module where users can upload images that need to be converted to an encrypted file type containing the uploaded image as a DDS texture.

So what I need to do is convert the uploaded image to dds file format.

Code:

```
$img = new Imagick('test.png'); //Load the uploaded image
$img->setformat('dds'); //Set the format to dds
$img->setImageCompression(Imagick::COMPRESSION_DXT3); //Set compression method
$img->writeimage('test.dds'); //Write/save the dds texture
```

***The problem: the output file is always an empty, 0 byte file.***

PNG That needs to be converted: [test.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JTZ6A.png)

DDS That needs to be the output: [test.dds](http://www40.zippyshare.com/v/70264639/file.html)

Maybe I need other version Imagick or ImageMagick?

My **old** version of these are:

1. PHP 5.5.15
2. Imagick 3.1.2-5.5-ts-vc11-x86
3. ImageMagick 6.8.4-0-Q16-x86

I am currently testing on Windows 8.1 x64.

Any suggestion/help would be appreciated.

**Edit:** Edited the question, hopefully its clear now what I am trying to achieve.

**Solved**: The problem was the version of ImageMagick that had no support for DDS write.

Installed ImageMagick 6.8.6-10-Q16-x86 since the DDS write support was added in that version (newer versions caused the imagick not to be loaded).

Current version of what I use and works:

1. PHP 5.5.15
2. Imagick 3.1.2-5.5-ts-vc11-x86
3. **ImageMagick 6.8.6-10-Q16-x86**

Comment: Please can you rewrite your question; it is very unclear what you are actually trying to do. You don't need to give a long description, you just need to give the code you're using, maybe a link to an example image file if you think it is necessary, and a description of how the code doesn't do what you're expecting.

Comment: Hello, Thanks for the comment. Edited the question (added input/output image links as well), hopefully its clear now what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: Can you check if "\Imagick::queryformats();" lists DDS as a supported format. Your code works fine for me on a Centos box.

Comment: I just checked and yes it is listed. [Imagick::queryformats(); Output](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=ZhQMcsJ4)  Could be something related to the version I have installed(?)

Comment: Maybe. Can you run the command through ImageMagick on the command line which I guess would be "convert -define dds:compression=dxt3 testDDS.png testCLI.dds"

Comment: Output from the command line: convert.exe: no encode delegate for this image format `testCLI.dds' @ warning/constitute.c/WriteImage/1224.

I checked via command line also the format list and I just noticed this: DDS* DDS       r--   Microsoft DirectDraw Surface

Looks like the version I use only supports reading so I would have to update ImageMagick, however I'm not sure if compatible php_imagick is available for newer version of ImageMagick

Comment: Do you really need DXT3? Is DXT1 or DXT5 not acceptable?

Comment: The dds files are used for a game where any DXT is supported but DXT3 has been picked to use (probably would be better to use DXT5 for better results).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the debugging above the issue is that your version of ImageMagick doesn't support writing DXT3 compressed DDS files.

The options to solve this problem are:

1. Use a different compression format - DXT5 might be okay, but it's not exactly the same as DXT3.
2. Upgrade to a newer version of ImageMagick and Imagick that support writing in DXT3 format.

Comment: I ended up testing some versions and fortunately the version where DDS write support has been added (6.8.6-10) is the last version of ImageMagick that I was able to get to work with Imagick 3.1.2-5.5-ts-vc11-x86 (everything above ImageMagick 6.8.6-10 was causing the imagick not to be loaded)

Comment: ImageMagick has no support for writing DXT3 files. Only support for DXT1 and DXT5 has been added. We might add support for DXT3 in the future.